# C++ Winsock recv hook Detours

Tags: c++, dll, hook, winsock2, detours

i want to write a .dll. My Targetapplication is a Game and use winsock. The .dll should write all things in a Console what the Game (Targetapplication) recives through the recv function in winsock. I've created a C++ Win32 Console Application in Visual Studio 2012 Professional, choosed .dll and Empty project.

My Code in main.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <detours.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment (lib, "detours")

typedef int (WINAPI *MyRecv) (SOCKET, char, int, int);

MyRecv OrigRecv = NULL;

int WINAPI RecvDetour(SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags)
{
    cout << *buf << "   -   " << len << endl;
    return OrigRecv(s, *buf, len, flags);
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE module, DWORD Reason, LPVOID reserved)
{
    switch (Reason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        cout << "Starting.." << endl;
        OrigRecv = (MyRecv)DetourFunction((PBYTE)recv, (PBYTE)RecvDetour);
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
}
```

I don't able to compile this. There are some Errors. Do anybody see a error in this code?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Post error messages verbatim in your question please.

Comment: Its German, but maybe it's helping http://pastebin.com/KnSahAeZ

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062091/detour-hook-send-recv-winsock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyRecv` is declared wrong.  The second parameter needs to be `char*` instead of `char`.

Also, your detour is outputting the receive buffer before it has been populated.  You need to call the original `recv()` function first and then you can output what it receives. Also, be sure to take into account that the data will not be null terminated.

```
typedef int (WINAPI *MyRecv) (SOCKET, char*, int, int);

MyRecv OrigRecv = NULL;

int WINAPI RecvDetour(SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags)
{
    int ret = OrigRecv(s, buf, len, flags);
    if (ret > 0)
        cout.write(buf, ret) << "   -   " << ret << endl;
}
```

See this earlier question:

[Detour hook send/recv winsock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062091/detour-hook-send-recv-winsock)